# Displaying Video from webcam in opencv on GTK+

Tags: opencv, gtk

I'm new to this and was wondering what i need to do to my open cv code to display using gtk.
Does it need to be converted or what?

Comment: Did you figure out how to display video in GTK+. I have the same requirment

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to do using Python. Here is a class that I've written to control a webcam using OpenCV and convert the frames to a NumPy array:

https://github.com/ptomato/REP-instrumentation/blob/master/rep/generic/opencv_webcam.py

After that, you can use [`gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_array()`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkpixbuf.html#function-gdk--pixbuf-new-from-array) to create a pixbuf which you can then create a `gtk.Image` from. Note that PyGTK needs to be compiled with NumPy support for this to work.

You can also use Matplotlib to display the frame in a GTK user interface. Here's another class that I've written that does that:

https://github.com/ptomato/Beams/blob/4276a1b98d4df2843d3e22b1be99ea0cabb4f6d4/src/CameraImage.py

Comment: Thanks but i have no knowledge of python whatsoever. I would be hoping to use C

Comment: Hello, DO you still have the code you posted available? I need to do something like this in python but I've been having some trouble to understand how to do it, so your code would help a lot! Thanks!